# Black Status bar in Xcode 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, statusbar

I am working an iOS application in Xcode 9.0 in which I am presenting a view controller on another controller (which is in the stack of navigation controller). The presented view controller showing a black status bar. If I add the same controller as a child view controller than it works fine with white status bar. I know to change the background color of status bar and style, but i want to know why black status bar is showing.

```
TutorialScreenVC *tutVC = [[APP_SERVICES getMainStoryBoard] 
               instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TutorialScreenVC"];

tutVC.isComingFromStat = YES;
[self presentViewController:tutVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

[image]